# Как создать scrollbar и обрабатывать gdi объекты?

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня создан scrollbar

```
case WM_SIZE:
        // Получаю размеры клиентской области 
        yClient = HIWORD(lparam);
        xClient = LOWORD(lparam);

        // Заполняю структуру для горизонтальной прокрутки
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = xClient - 1;
        si.nPage = xClient;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);

        // Заполняю структуру для вертикальной прокрутки
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = xClient - 1;
        si.nPage = yClient;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_HSCROLL:
        // Заполняю структуру для горизонтальной прокрутки
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;

        // корректирую движок
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
        xPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {
            // нажать на левую стрелку
        case SB_LINELEFT:
            si.nPos -= 5;
            break;

            // нажать на правую стрелку
        case SB_LINERIGHT:
            si.nPos += 5;
            break;

            // перелистнуть страницу влево
        case SB_PAGELEFT:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // перелистнуть страницу вправо
        case SB_PAGERIGHT:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // перетащить ползунок
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        //ввожу данные движка и делаю перерасчет
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);

        // если положение движка изменилось двигаю картинку по горизонтали
        if (si.nPos != xPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, xPos - si.nPos, 0, NULL, NULL);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
        // Заполняю структуру для вертикальной прокрутки
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // корректирую движок
        yPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {

            // нажатие клавиши HOME
        case SB_TOP:
            si.nPos = si.nMin;
            break;

            // нажатие клавиши END
        case SB_BOTTOM:
            si.nPos = si.nMax;
            break;

            // нажать на верхнюю стрелку
        case SB_LINEUP:
            si.nPos -= 5;
            break;

            // нажать на нижнюю стрелку
        case SB_LINEDOWN:
            si.nPos += 5;
            break;

            // перелистнуть страницу вверх
        case SB_PAGEUP:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // перелистнуть страницу вниз
        case SB_PAGEDOWN:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // перетащить ползунок
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        //ввожу данные движка и делаю перерасчет
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // если положение движка изменилось двигаю картинку по вертикали
        if (si.nPos != yPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, yPos - si.nPos, NULL, NULL);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }
```

При скролинге, все bitmap объекты расплываются, как можно это испарвить?

```
void Main::paint(HWND hwnd)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

FILE* conin = stdin;
FILE* conout = stdout;
FILE* conerr = stderr;
AllocConsole();
AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
freopen_s(&conin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&conout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&conerr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
SetConsoleTitle(L"AdminConsole");

Graphics* gt = new Graphics(hdc);
gt->DrawCachedBitmap(backgroundCachedBitmap.get(), 0, 0);
Color rect(255, 255, 255);
SolidBrush blueBrush(rect);
SCROLLINFO      si;             //структура si
GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
/*
gt->FillRectangle(&blueBrush, Rect(0, 0, Const::windowHeight, menuBarHeight));*/
gt->DrawCachedBitmap(logoCachedBitmap.get(), 20, si.nPos);

gt->FillRectangle(&blueBrush, getAboutScrollBarButtonRect());

closeButton->draw(gt);
minButton->draw(gt);

delete gt;
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это конечно хорошо что вы привели код обработки сообщения изменения размеров окна, но где обработка сообщений отрисовки?

Comment: `InvalidateRect` делает предшествующий вызов `ScrollWindow` бесполезным, так как все равно должно будет перерисовываться все содержимое окна.

Comment: WM_PAINTL:{ 
paint(hwnd);
break;
}

Comment: Без InvalidateRect тоже самое, точнее, результат на фото без него, он оказался в коде по ошибке)